# calculate distance between current coordinates and a list of coordinates

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, coordinates, haversine

I am trying to calculate the straight line distance between coordinates. I can successfully do this using with hard coded values, however my problem comes in when I have a list of coordinates. S basically the first set of coordinates will always be my current location which I can successfully get. The second set of coordinates are coming from a JSON file as seen below.

```
[
    {
      "LocationID": 407,
      "LocationName": "Free State",
      "CustomerName": "Build It - Botshabelo ",
      "ContactNo": "051 - 534 4072",
      "Address": "75 Blue Street, Botshabelo",
      "Zipcode": null,
      "Longitude": "26,704671",
      "Latitude": "-29,199533",
      "Status": 1,
      "CreatedDate": "25:29,0",
      "CreatedBy": 1,
      "ModifiedDate": "25:29,0",
      "ModifiedBy": 1,
      "ShopType": "Retails",
      "Region": null,
      "FIELD16": "Closed "
    },
    {
      "LocationID": 408,
      "LocationName": "Free State",
      "CustomerName": "Cashbuild - Thabanchu",
      "ContactNo": "051 - 875 1590",
      "Address": "Brug St, Thaba Nchu",
      "Zipcode": null,
      "Longitude": "26,779109",
      "Latitude": "-29,196689",
      "Status": 1,
      "CreatedDate": "25:29,0",
      "CreatedBy": 1,
      "ModifiedDate": "25:29,0",
      "ModifiedBy": 1,
      "ShopType": "Retails",
      "Region": null,
      "FIELD16": "Closed "
    },
    {
      "LocationID": 409,
      "LocationName": "Free State",
      "CustomerName": "Ladybrand Mica",
      "ContactNo": "082 - 568 5387",
      "Address": "17 Joubert St, Ladybrand",
      "Zipcode": null,
      "Longitude": "27,458835",
      "Latitude": "-29,191979",
      "Status": 1,
      "CreatedDate": "25:29,0",
      "CreatedBy": 1,
      "ModifiedDate": "25:29,0",
      "ModifiedBy": 1,
      "ShopType": "Retails",
      "Region": null,
      "FIELD16": ""
    }
]
```

I am looping through the array to get the latitudes and longitudes

```
  this.http.get('assets/stores.json').subscribe(data => {
    this.places = data;

    for(var i = 0; i < this.places.length; i++){
      this.placePOS = this.places[i].Latitude, this.places[i].Longitude;
      var distance = this.distance(this.currentLat, this.currentLon, this.places[i].Latitude, this.places[i].Longitude, 'K');
    }

  });
```

The distance function is created here

```
  distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, unit) {
    var radlat1 = Math.PI * lat1/180
    var radlat2 = Math.PI * lat2/180
    var radlon1 = Math.PI * lon1/180
    var radlon2 = Math.PI * lon2/180
    var theta = lon1-lon2
    var radtheta = Math.PI * theta/180
    var dist = Math.sin(radlat1) * Math.sin(radlat2) + Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);
    dist = Math.acos(dist)
    dist = dist * 180/Math.PI
    dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515
    if (unit=="K") { dist = dist * 1.609344 }
    if (unit=="N") { dist = dist * 0.8684 }
    return dist
}
```

When I run the code I get a NaN. Please assist

Comment: `I get a NaN.`   Where, what line?

Comment: The NaN is in the for loop on this line var distance = ....

Comment: Ok wait, if I look at the JSON file the lat and lon is enclosed in "" and the distance function expects a value without "". This maybe causing the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my konwledge wenn you read the value for **this.places[i].Latitude** this is not a Number so it would be necessary to convert this String to a number before you send it to the function or within the funktion.

Either with **Number()** or with **parseFloat()**

As pointed out by @Keith for **parseFloat()** both conversations are not able to handle the comma in the original JSON object. **Number()** would produce again NaN and **parseFloat()** rounds the number to the nearest full number. So it ist necessary to replace the comma from the JSON object with a dot.

thanks @Keith

Comment: parseFloat() is a good idea, but it won't be why he's getting NaN as JS will automatically convert here.

Comment: parseFloat fixes it, converts the JSON lat and lon to numbers

Comment: @eohdev  No it won't, check your numbers.. When you have figured out there wrong, I'll let you know what other problem you have.  `parseFloat` has just hidden the issue.. :)

Answer (score 3):

Seen as nobody else has spotted it,.. And @eohdev has now gone away thinking the results are correct, just because they are now not giving `NaN`, I'll post the main reason for the problem.

`parseFloat` is good practice, but it's not what was causing the problem.. Javascript can often work out type automatically.. eg.  `"20" / 4` will equal `5`, even though `20` was a string.  `"20" - "5"` will equal 15,.  The one that JS can't work out automatically would be `"20" + "5"` this would be 205..  This is because you can concatenate strings, and add number so it can't automatically choose, this is why parseFloat etc is a good idea.

But back to the problem here, it's the source data.. 
`"Longitude": "27,458835"`
That number is not a valid floating point number, floating point numbers in JS don't have commas.

So why did it look like parseFloat worked you ask,.. well `parseFloat("27,458835")` will result in `27`.. Oh, dear.. Unless your distance calculation is meant to be truncated to the nearest degree, it's maybe not what your after.

So the problem wasn't parseFloat was missing, but the source data is using commas, instead of full stops for it's decimal's. So if you change the commas to full stops your current code will work, but I would also say keep the parseFloats too for good measure.

Comment: thanks Keith, I have just replaced the "," with "." so that ParseFloat does not exclude full values

Comment: So the current accepted answer is wrong.. Even if you remove parseFloat and just change the commas, your current code would have worked.  Anyway, can I have at least an up-vote.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You get a NaN, when you try to perform some mathematical operations on variables which are not numbers.
In your problem, the documents array you have, latitude and longitude are in string format and you are not parsing float anywhere. First convert those strings to numbers and then do the mathematical operations, you desire.

PS: I can give you the code but it would be better if you try it out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You were having issue in distance function. you need to use parseFloat for lon(s) and lat(s) to convert them into numbers from string.

I tried to change your code a little bit. https://jshttps://jsfiddle.net/startsco/z5n7q2zn/10/fiddle.net/startsco/z5n7q2zn/10/

run it and check your console.

Comment: I commented out `this.` because I am not working inside any object. If you want to make it work inside some object, use need to use `this.`

Comment: `parseFloat` is a good idea, but it won't fix the problem here.  Unfortunately @eohdev has now gone away getting numbers for distance, but the number will be wrong.. :(  It won't be NaN anymore, but it wont be the right numbers he's getting..

Comment: Uh, Why? I mean, it's working as expected. I didn't have any look at distance function. But when I used parseFloat, its working and giving the result in console.

Comment: You will get results, but they will be wrong... :(   The problem is a little bit more subtle that just using parseFloat.. :(